# Put $_GET parameter in php variable

Tags: php, get

Is it possible to take $_GET parameter from the url and put it in php variable without using foreach?
If I do:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

I will get the result:

```
array(1) { ["block_simple_clock"]=> string(0) "" }
```

I need to put that value block_simple_clock in a string variable, and I can do that with a foreach:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key);
}
```

But I would really like to take that value without a foreach if it is possible. I hate using foreach for such a trivial problem :)

Sorry for confusion, that block_simple_clock is a variable, and it can be a different value, I am sending this value with this code:

```
    foreach ($pluginlist->plugins as $key => $plugin) {

        if (empty($plugin->component)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (in_array($plugin->component, $arr)) {
            if (!in_array($plugin->component, $contribs)) {
                $target_url = new moodle_url('redirect.php');

                $mform->addElement('advcheckbox', $plugin->component, "<a href={$target_url}?$plugin->component target='_blank'>" . $plugin->name . "</a>", '', array(0, 1));
                }
            }
        $requestedPluginIdCounter++;
    }
```

As you can see the $plugin->component is the value that I am sending via $_GET.

Comment: `$variable = $_GET['block_simple_clock'];`?

Comment: can you please show how you passing it? your url

Comment: Its not totally obvious if you want the value contained in the array OR the name of the array, Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
$t = array_keys($_GET);
echo $t[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$variable = $_GET['block_simple_clock'];
```

OR

```
 $variable = $_REQUEST['block_simple_clock'];
```

Comment: I think the existing comment from @JonStirling is quite adequate for such a simple (php 101) question

Comment: so i have made changes, this can also help someone..many people look for the answers not for the comments @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly which ones you need, you can use

```
$var = $_GET['name-in-get'];
```

You mays want to use the function

```
extract( $_GET );
```

Which creates **global** variables with the name of the key :

```
//suppose GET = $_GET['name']
extract( $_GET );
echo $name; //will echo $_GET['name']
```

Remember to **ALWAYS** filter gets and posts values, since they are user input (obviously it depends what you do with them, but especially if they're used for database purposes, it is extremely important)
For more information, see [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I have added a name=$plugin->component, and was able to extract the variable with that $_GET["name"] :)